# Entity Framework 4.1 Mapping Relationships by setting Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity, code-first

How does one tell the bloody Entity Framework to map relationship to the columns one wants!

I have 1 table:

```
     public class ShedPart
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public int ParentGroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }           

        [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
        [InverseProperty("ParentGroupId")]
        public ICollection<Part> ParentParts { get; set; }
    }
```

Each Part *can* have multiple ParentParts...

The SQL generated is this :

```
 SELECT
`Project1`.`Id`, 
`Project1`.`Name`, 
`Project1`.`GroupId`, 
`Project1`.`ParentGroupId`, 
`Project1`.`GroupName`,
`Project1`.`C1`, 
`Project1`.`Id1`, 
`Project1`.`Name1`, 
`Project1`.`GroupId1`, 
`Project1`.`ParentGroupId1`, 
`Project1`.`GroupName1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`GroupId`, 
`Extent1`.`ParentGroupId`, 
`Extent1`.`GroupName`, 
`Extent2`.`Id` AS `Id1`, 
`Extent2`.`Name` AS `Name1`, 
`Extent2`.`GroupId` AS `GroupId1`, 
`Extent2`.`ParentGroupId` AS `ParentGroupId1`, 
`Extent2`.`GroupName` AS `GroupName1`
CASE WHEN (`Extent2`.`Id` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS `C1`
FROM `Parts` AS `Extent1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Parts` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent2`.`GroupId`) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Id` ASC, 
`C1` ASC}
```

As you can see that is wrong as it is joining the tables on Id => GroupId, when I am trying to join by ParentGroupId => GroupId.

So I try this:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Part>()
            .HasMany(s => s.ParentParts)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.ToTable("parts");
                         m.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
                         m.MapRightKey("ParentGroupId");
                     });
```

Does the same thing..... Seems Entity Framework will only map to the Key Column! How do get it to relate the columns I want?

Comment: You want to have Part, Group and, many-to-many junction table in single table? Impossible. From your entity it is absolutely not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Basically, if u could ignore the Group property, all I want is a 'Part' object, which has a 'ParentParts' property (being a collection of the same 'Part' object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to extract

```
[Key]
public int GroupId { get; set; }        
public int ParentGroupId { get; set; }
```

to a Group table which has a self join ?
this way you could have a navigation property for Part -> Group.

group would contain a collection of parts and its parent group.

GroupId would then be a primary key and you could self reference for the ParentGroupId

Comment: Thanks for that I'll have a go at redesigning my object as it would seem the set up is wrong meaning the poor EF4.1 framework can't deal with it!